# Accidentally killed plasma

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, kde, plasma, plasma-5

I accidentally pressed ctrl + alt + esc, clicking on the process in the task manager, but it didnt work, and it selected the whole plasma desktop and got killed, is there a quick fix to start up plasma again by opening a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command `plasmashell` and see if that works.

If only Plasma crashed, try `plasma5-desktop --replace`.

This will kill all remaining instances of Plasma and start a new one.

Comment: And how do i open the terminal? ctrl+shift+t does not work.

Comment: @userino Control Alt T?

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: I can always just restart my computer, but i would like an easy fix if this happens again, ill be sleeping now, see you in 10 hours.

Comment: I understand. Use Control Alt F1 to switch to a Terminal and then try my solution and Control Alt F7 to get back to the graphical interface. Oh, and don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it worked :)

Comment: No, does not work since i killed the plasma process, it wont just restart if i change terminals, but i can use that to open it.

Comment: Tried plasmashell, "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display"

Comment: @userino then I'm not sure how to help you... :(